# Possible to multi-thread inside the loop of simulation in an efficient manner?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

My question is about how to properly design the following multi-threading in a way that does not actually decrease the performance of my simulation instead of increasing it.

Suppose that you have a class called `MyClass`, which hold a couple of big arrays (around 500MB each) and a function that processes information by using such arrays:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int *data1 = new int[ARRAY_SIZE]();
    int *data2 = new int[ARRAY_SIZE]();

public:
    void fillData(); //any function that fills the inner data
    void processData(const int iteration);
}
```

Every iteration of the simulation, 4 instances of `MyClass` are processed. In my ideal world, what I would like to do is to pass each each of such instances to one thread and then inside each thread, call `instance.processData()`. Using `#include <thread>` it looks like the following:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass inst1,inst2, inst3, inst4;

    //<----- here you would have code that fills the arrays inside each instance of MyClass

    for(int iteration=0; iteration<MAX_ITERATIONS; iteration++)
    {
        std::thread t1(&MyClass::processData, &inst1, iteration);
        std::thread t2(&MyClass::processData, &inst2, iteration);
        std::thread t3(&MyClass::processData, &inst3, iteration);
        std::thread t4(&MyClass::processData, &inst4, iteration);

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The reason why I am dispatching the `MyClass` instances to the threads every iteration is that after `processData` ends for each instance, I do **comparisons between the results of the data in each instance every iteration**.

The problem is that the code as it is described is actually extremely slower than the non-multhithreded version (like orders of magnitude slower). The question then becomes: what am I doing wrong? Are there ways to improve on that, considering that I have to compare the results of the processing of each instance at the end of every iteration?

PS1: I absolutely cannot paralelize the process contained in `processData`. This is a 100% out of question.

PS2: while I cannot disclose anything related to the real code in itself, in case it helps I could take the snippets I wrote above and make them into a real compilable example. Although I think the point might be clear enough without it.

Comment: Doing thread overhead WITHIN the loop is VERY inefficient.

Comment: Regarding `PS2`, yes, please provide a [mcve]. In particular it is difficult to address your remark about  "*comparisons between the results of the data in each instance every iteration*" without any such code. Since this is about performance, the example should also have a similar performance characteristics, such that an improvement in your the MCVE likely translates to your real code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be causing you to see a decrease in performance using four threads rather than one. Here's the basic things to check for:

- Parallelization Overhead: This is the cost of creating and synchronizing threads. If the amount of work done in `processData` is low and you have a large number of iterations, then thread creation and destruction costs could be an issue. If you have any synchronization constructs within `processData()`, such as barriers, locks, or atomic operations, these could be a source of the slow down.
- [Thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)): When a single thread executes, the set of active memory (that which is being written to and read from) is often much smaller than when multiple threads are running. This can result in a much larger number of cache misses (i.e., due to multiple threads having to share L2 and L3 caches). If your program is exceeding the amount of physical memory on your system (i.e., swapping), multiple threads may result in page thrashing, whereas a signle thread would not.
- Resource Contention: If your processes are reading/writing to disk or the network, you may be experiancing something similar to thrashing with that resource, where the differen threads prevent each other from accessing it efficiently.
- [False Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing): This is where threads write and read to different locations on the same cache line, repeatedly causing computations to be thrown away as cache lines are invalidated and refreshed.

Questions to allow for better diagnoses:

1. How long is the total wall clock time of execution per iteration when run serially?
2. How long is the total wall clock time of execution per iteration when with four threads?
3. What type of operation/algorithm is `processData()` (e.g., sorting, sparse linear algebra, dense linear
4. What are the physical specifications of this system (i.e., how many physical and logical cores does it have, how big are the caches, how much physical memory does it have)?
5. How many iterations are performed?